# Sending bitcoins in regtest to client

Tags: regtest

I have bitcoind hosted on a local machine and I would like to set up a remote client to do some bitcoin URI testing on another local machine. I have Bitcoin-QT installed on the client and updated client bitcoin.conf as following

```
regtest=1
connect=0.0.0.0
rpc_connect = 192.168.0.252 #Address of host
```

In the client Bitcoin-QT, I copy the receiving address and try to have the host send regtest coins to the address with the command

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest sendtoaddress muteqiroK9LNRAUppnicQepBhPvaEuW8TG 1.00
```

This does not work. Can anyone give me some direction as to how I would get this working?

Thank you!

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, here is what I did.

client bitcoin.conf

```
regtest=1
addnode=$ADDR_OF_HOST
```

then I opened port 18444 on host and all transactions synced on client.